# read/write struct to a socket

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I am trying to write from client a struct to the server with socket.

the struct is :

```
typedef struct R
{
int a;
int b;
double c;
double d;
double result[4]; 
}R;
```

The struct is the same at the 2 programs(server,client) and i malloc for the struct in both.

the client program:

struct R* r;

malloc..

...(fill the struct with data)

write(socket_fd,(void*)r,size of(R));

---

the Server program:

struct R* r;

malloc..

read(client_fd,(R*)r,size of(R));

---

This is not passing the struct from client to server..

How to write the struct to the server by socket??

Comment: What you show looks ok, however there are a lots of other things (that you do not show) that could be/go wrong when transmitting data via sockets.

Comment: like what? i tryied to sent just int or double and it is working... but the struct not

Comment: Assuming memory handling and socket setup and connect/accept is done properly, endianness and padding aren't an issue, then closely read the documentation for read()/write() and learn that those two functions (at least for sockets) do not necessarily read/wrtite as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data expected had been read/written is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Answer (score 3):

Some basic elements of network programming are:

1. One read or write call might not write the total bytes you intend to
   read/write. Check the return value of call. It would return number
   of bytes read/written. If less bytes have been written, you should
   call write in a loop until all data has been written. Same applies
   to read.
2. Endianess of machine also matters. If you wrote an int which was
   little endian (e.g. x86), when travelling on the network it would be converted into a
   big endian value. You need to use apis such as **htons**, **ntohs** in POSIX to
   accommodate that.

These are just starting points, but the most likely reasons of data not reaching destination in the form as you expected.

Comment: To elaborate: 1) Familiarize yourself with ntohl(), htonl(), etc., and 2) *always* do your read() inside of a loop, *always* check the return/error status.  Check out [Beej's Guide tp Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) - it's an excellent resource!  IMHO...

Comment: Also, `sizeof(int)` and alignment rules may not be the same across architectures. It is generally best to explicitly fill out the individual bytes in an array of `unsigned char`: `buf[0] = (a >> 24) & 0xff; buf[1] = (a >> 16) & 0xff; ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are getting some data, but not in the form you are expecting. If so, it might also help to add a breakpoint in gdb and inspect the memory of r, in the client code.
You could fill the struct in sender code with 0xdeadbeef or similar debug strings(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values), to identify your data in the client memory more easily. I have found that very helpful for debugging. Like some of the other answers mentioned, endianess and partial data might be the problem. Checking the return values and error codes will help too.